# Redis : Pros and Cons for following two approaches

Tags: data-structures, redis, hashmap

I have a lot of javascript objects like:

```
var obj1 = {"key1" : value1, "key2" : value2, ...}
var obj2 = {"key3" : value3, "key4" : value4, ...}
```

and so on...

Following are the two approaches :

1. Store each object as Redis Hash i.e. one-to-one mapping.
2. Have one Redis Hash(bucketing can be done for better performance), store each object as stringified object in each key of hash i.e. for each object having a key value pair in the Redis Hash. Parse the object when we need to use the object.

1) -> Takes more space than 2) but has better performance than 2)

2) -> Takes less space than 1) but has worse performance than 1)

Is there a way to determine which approach would be better in the long run?

**Update:** This data is used on the client side (AngularJS), so all parsing of stringified JSON is done in the frontend.

Comment: Do you need to search on individual fields, or are you just looking for an id->document mapping?

Comment: Yes, I need to search on individual fields too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would probably be solved by deciding which method minimises the number of steps required to extract the required data from redis.

**Case 1:** Lots of nested objects
If your objects have a lot of nesting, ie objects within objects, like this,
   `obj = {key1:{key2:value1, key:3{key4:value2}}}`

You should probably stringify and store them.
Because Redis does not allow nesting of data structures. You can't store a hash within another hash.
And storing the name of hash2 as a key within hash1 and querying hash2 after getting hash1 and so on is unnecessarily complex and has a lot of queries. In this case all you have to do is get the entire string from Redis and `JSON.parse` it. and you can get whatever data you want from the Object.

**Case 2:** No nested objects.
But on the other hand, if there is no nesting of objects and you store it as a string, you have to `JSON.parse()` every time you get the data from Redis. And parsing JSON is blocking and is CPU intensive. [Node.js: does JSON.parse block the event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842606/node-js-does-json-parse-block-the-event-loop)

Redis documentation also says that hashes are encoded in a very small space, so you should try representing your data using hashes every time it is possible. http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

So, in this case, you could probably go ahead and store them all as individual hashes as querying a particular value will be a lot easier.

---------Update---------
Even if the JSON parsing is done on the client, try not to do an extra computation needlessly :)
But nested objects are easier to store and query as a string. Otherwise, you'll have to query more than one hash table. In this case storing as stringified object might just be better for performance.

Redis stores small hashes very efficiently. So much that storing multiple small hashmaps is more memory efficient than one big hashmap.
the number of keys deciding about the encoding to use can be found in redis.conf
`hash-max-zipmap-entries 512`
also the value of each key should be `hash-max-zipmap-value 64`
So, you can now decide on the basis of nesting of your objects, number of Hash Keys below which Redis is more memory efficient and the value assigned to your keys.

Do go through http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

Comment: This data will be used in Frontend(i guess I should have mentioned that), and I am using angular for parsing the stringified JSON and hence server has no load of parsing any object.

Comment: @AmanGupta even then, nested objects are better stored as strings.  Otherwise you'll have to query multiple hashmaps to get the data you want.
If no nested objects, go ahead and store them as individual hashes. You might also want to store them as individual hashes if the number of objects are greater then zipmap entries value.

Comment: I dont have nested objects, so that problem we can take away. The second approach is also used by Instagram , so I was curious why they are doing like that and they would be having very solid reason for doing so.

Comment: hmmm. I actually don't see a reason why the second approach (as mentioned in your question) should be used if there is no nesting. Redis documentation clearly prefers the first approach when it comes to storing hashes with respect to memory consumption. Although a little slower performance wise.